# Codeigniter Page navigation error

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am new to codeigniter. I need help in navigating from one page to another page.
I'm working on a small crud app where dashboard is like admin folder.
I have an admin called localhost/koeweb/dashboard which loads fine.
now trying to go to another page within the admin, say localhost/koeweb/dashboard/page2 and i get `404 Page Not Found.`

**Here is my code**

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('parish_model');
  }

  public function index() {
    $this->load->view('dashboard/inc/header_view');
    $data['query'] = $this->parish_model->getParish();
    $this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('dashboard/inc/footer_view');
  }

  public function page2() {
    $this->load->view('dashboard/inc/header_view');
    $this->load->view('dashboard/add_parish');
    $this->load->view('dashboard/inc/footer_view');
  }
}
```

Comment: can you access your page2 with this URL http://localhost/koeweb/index.php/dashboard/page2 ?

Comment: do you have an htaccess in your document root?

Comment: Please check your application/config/config.php ($config['index_page']). If you have rewrite rules set in .htaccess file then $config['index_page']='' otherwise $config['index_page']='index.php'

Answer (score 0):

Create `.htaccess`  in your document root with the following contents

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Or try to access the url with `index.php`

Like

```
http://localhost/koeweb/index.php/dashboard/page2
```